# How can I enable Mountain Lion Airplay mirroring through command line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, script, osx-mountain-lion, airplay

I want to enable/disable airplay mirroring with an script and I don't know how to find what commands are executed when Airplay is activated.

Any idea about how to do it or where to search?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with AppleScript. First create "EnableAirplay.scpt" and paste following content in it:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click pop up button 1 of window 1
        click menu item 2 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

Then you can run this script with following command:

```
osascript EnableAirPlay.scpt
```

This will automate enabling AirPlay. For more detail you can refer to following references:

- http://oguzarduc.blogspot.com/2012/08/applescript-for-activating-airplay.html
- http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_running_applescripts_terminal

Answer (score 0):

Check this page:
http://oguzarduc.blogspot.com/2012/08/applescript-for-activating-airplay.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.